# PHP script execution won't start at break point

Tags: vagrant, phpstorm, xdebug

I'm running PHP 5.5.9 on Ubuntu 4.19, Vagrant, Virtual box on Mac. I'm trying to use debugger on PhpStorm (2016.2.1) , so I followed couple of tutorials how to do that, enabled XDebug 2.2.3. My current status is:

- When checked from PhpStorm (Run -> Web Server Debug Validation) everything is ok, no errors.
- On Google Chrome I've installed "Jet Brains IDE support" plugin
- On PhpStorm when I click on "Start listening for PHP debug connections" it turns green - everything fine here too, I guess.
- PhpStorm, when I click "Debug" icon, Chrome starts well, opens page I'm trying to debug and I get balloon tip from Chrome: *"JetBrains IDE Support" is debugging this browser* and small bug icon turns green ("debug" mode).

So apparently everything is ok, but script execution just won't stop at my break point. Any idea what I'm missing here. Here is my php.ini settings regarding xdebug:

```
Directive   Local Value Master Value
xdebug.auto_trace   Off Off
xdebug.cli_color    0   0
xdebug.collect_assignments  Off Off
xdebug.collect_includes On  On
xdebug.collect_params   0   0
xdebug.collect_return   Off Off
xdebug.collect_vars Off Off
xdebug.coverage_enable  On  On
xdebug.default_enable   On  On
xdebug.dump.COOKIE  no value    no value
xdebug.dump.ENV no value    no value
xdebug.dump.FILES   no value    no value
xdebug.dump.GET no value    no value
xdebug.dump.POST    no value    no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST no value    no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER  no value    no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION no value    no value
xdebug.dump_globals On  On
xdebug.dump_once    On  On
xdebug.dump_undefined   Off Off
xdebug.extended_info    On  On
xdebug.file_link_format no value    no value
xdebug.idekey   PHPSTORM    PHPSTORM
xdebug.max_nesting_level    100 100
xdebug.overload_var_dump    On  On
xdebug.profiler_aggregate   Off Off
xdebug.profiler_append  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_enable  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_output_dir  /tmp    /tmp
xdebug.profiler_output_name cachegrind.out.%p   cachegrind.out.%p
xdebug.remote_autostart Off Off
xdebug.remote_connect_back  Off Off
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time    3600    3600
xdebug.remote_enable    On  On
xdebug.remote_handler   dbgp    dbgp
xdebug.remote_host  192.168.33.22   192.168.33.22
xdebug.remote_log   no value    no value
xdebug.remote_mode  req req
xdebug.remote_port  9000    9000
xdebug.scream   Off Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace Off Off
xdebug.show_local_vars  Off Off
xdebug.show_mem_delta   Off Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger Off Off
xdebug.trace_format 0   0
xdebug.trace_options    0   0
xdebug.trace_output_dir /tmp    /tmp
xdebug.trace_output_name    trace.%c    trace.%c
xdebug.var_display_max_children 128 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data 512 512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth    3   3
```

**Update 1**

On @LazyOne suggestion I checked on php error log and there was an error:

```
PHP:  syntax error, unexpected '=' in /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini on line 1935
Failed loading /usr/lib/php5/20100525/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php5/20100525/xdebug.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I checked for missing xdebug.so file and it's parent dir was wrong. On my machine it was "20121212", so I changed that, restarted apache and after I'm getting following content in error log:

```
[Fri Aug 26 12:15:55.407344 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 22840] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
PHP Warning:  Module 'xdebug' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[Fri Aug 26 12:15:56.415611 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 22903] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.19 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Aug 26 12:15:56.415660 2016] [core:notice] [pid 22903] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

That's all there is in php error file. @LazyOne, is that the error log file you were talking about or there is some other?

**Update 2**

I added following configuration to my php.ini file:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension = /usr/lib/php5/20121212/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_host = 192.168.33.22
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.idekey = PHPSTORM
```

**Update 3**

xdebug log follows:

```
Log opened at 2016-08-26 13:55:30
I: Connecting to configured address/port: 192.168.33.22:9000.
E: Could not connect to client. :-(
Log closed at 2016-08-26 13:55:30
```

Comment: 1) You do not need that Chrome plugin for PHP debug 2) *""JetBrains IDE Support" is debugging this browser"* this means that you are doing JavaScript debug and not PHP 3) https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+with+PhpStorm

Comment: Ok, Good to know. But what about php break points not stopping script execution?

Comment: Well ... how it can stop if you are NOT doing PHP debugging?.. If you are sure that you setup everything correctly and PHP debugging actually gets initiated but does not stop on breakpoints .. please provide xdebug log to start with.

Comment: To be honest I didn't even know that PHP Storm can debug JavaScript too. :) Anyway, I've updated my question above.

Comment: How did you loaded xdebug? Show me the actual line. This error could mean either your are loading it wrong (as ordinary extension) or it's indeed already loaded elsewhere (another .ini file -- on Linux it could be just like that -- just check `php -i` or `phpinfo()` output -- it will list all loaded config files in top table.

Comment: Updated my question with php.ini settings for xdebug. If that's not what you are asking for then please explain what do you mean by "loading xdebug".

Comment: Yes -- that's exactly what I meant. If you still have "Module 'xdebug' already loaded in Unknown on line 0" message then it must be loaded elsewhere. ALSO: how do you run PHP? Is it php-fpm or something different?

Comment: How to collect xdebug logs: https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_log

Comment: Updated my question with xdebug log output. And sorry, I'm not that experienced - I don't know how to check is my PHP fpm. I installed it simply with: sudo apt-get install -y php5

Comment: What is `192.168.33.22`? This has to be an IP of a computer where PhpStorm is running (as seen from computer where PHP gets executed). Also -- PhpStorm must be able to accept incoming connections on that xdebug port (TCP 9000) -- make sure that your firewall is allowing that (as it's xdebug who connects to IDE).

Comment: That's ip address of my virutal machine running on vagrat/virtual box. Vagrant is sharing /var/www/html so files are accessible also on mac side, where I'm running PHP Storm. And firewall is off on my computer.

Comment: That must be an IP of computer where PhpStorm is running as seen from within Virtual Machine. https://xdebug.org/docs/remote

Comment: Instead of specifying exact IP address you can try `xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1` option -- depending your your environment it may work just fine.